# Destructuring in React components

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There are a few articles stating that's best practice to use ES6 destructuring for React props & state.

Eg: `const { showModal, hideModal } = this.props;`

While I agree with this from the perspective of having much cleaner code, I had a discussion with one other developer suggesting that this should be done for class methods as well because it will bring a performance improvement.

I say it won't be any faster and also it will make the code more confusing.

Does anyone have any opinion on this?

Comment: Why would that be a performance improvement?

Comment: Your colleague's approach also has another disadvantage: If you're not autobinding the methods to the class instance, you'll be in for a surprise or two.

Comment: *"Does anyone have any opinion on this?"* Subjective questions are off topic. Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: Sorry I was ambiguous, but I think people got the point. Let me rephrase that for you: "What could be some benefits/drawbacks of using destructuring assignment?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it will not make your code any slower/faster. I am sure someone might come out with some crazy synthetic case that will show 10ms improvement over the set with 10000000 records with 1000 properties each, but - in real world applications readability and maintainability is way more important. And if your code is smaller and easier to read and understand - it will contain less mistakes and as the end result will be quicker.

My personal opinion on destructuring is that I does lead us to writing less code that is easier to read, both for variables and parameters. Lets take this code from [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Grid/Grid.example.js) for example:

```
_cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  if (columnIndex === 0) {
    return this._renderLeftSideCell({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style })
  } else {
    return this._renderBodyCell({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style })
  }
}
```

Here just by looking at the method declaration it is immediately obvious what parameters are.

And now  - compare it with this:

```
_cellRenderer (p) {
  if (p.columnIndex === 0) {
    return this._renderLeftSideCell({ columnIndex: p.columnIndex, key: p.key, rowIndex: p.rowIndex, style: p.style })
  } else {
    return this._renderBodyCell({ columnIndex: p.columnIndex, key: p.key, rowIndex: p.rowIndex, style: p.style })
  }
}
```

Way more code and not so clean and easy to read, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with [react-virtualised](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Grid/Grid.example.js) example as well.

But what about having here something like this?

```
const { _renderBodyCell, _renderLeftSideCell } = this;

_cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
  if (columnIndex === 0) {
    return _renderLeftSideCell({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style })
  } else {
    return _renderBodyCell({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style })
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should not do this because: 1) By looking at the code it will be hard to say what is being called. Is it member of the current class? Or maybe its is imported or global function? So you earn a bit shorter code but to understand what is actually happening - requires more investigation for the new maintainer. 2) You are loosing the power of modern IDEs: type `this.` and you immediately get all available members of the current class - this is really handy feature you do not want to loose.